# Can this be achieved using only htaccess?

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, wordpress

We are about to deploy a new internal website (new domain and all) and we would like to have existing user bookmarks still function. The catch is we have a bilingual website.

The old domain:

```
english: http://olddomain/route/to/some/post
french:  http://olddomain/fr/route/to/some/french/post
```

The new domains:

```
english: http://new-domain-en/route/to/some/post
french:  http://new-domain-fr/route/to/some/french/post
```

So right now, I have these two htaccess rules:

```
RewriteRule ^fr/(.*)$ http://new-domain-fr/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://new-domain-en/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Which would make anyone who visits `new-domain-fr` get redirected to the english website. The problem is both new domains point to the same server (and thus, the same htaccess file), and then wordpress will server the correct content from there.

Can this all be done via htaccess or should I write a php script to interpret URLs and route appropriately?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point olddomain to a new virtual host, or put the rewrite rules in the domain configuration instead of the .htaccess file.